# Can I trigger a plugin on the DynamicPropertyInstance entity?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I have a product record, let's name it "Subscription". It inherits a required property from its family which is an integer named "Duration". When I add this product to a quote I am prompted to enter the duration as expected.

I want CRM to recognise the duration when calculating the value of the quote.

At the moment I can add a line item for the subscription. I change the quantity to 5 to represent 5 users. The price is £10 which is the monthly price. I'm prompted to enter the duration property so I put 12 as it's an annual license.

As CRM ignores the duration property it values the quote at £50 when in reality this should be multiplied by the duration to get the correct value of £600.

I thought that triggering a plugin on the create/update of a Dynamic Property Instance would be the right way to go as I could jump up to the line item and alter the value. Unfortunately the plugin registration tool doesn't seem to list this entity as one I can trigger plugins against.

**How can I trigger a plugin on the DynamicPropertyInstance entity? If I can't, is there an alternate way to make CRM take the property into account when calculating value?**

Answer (score 1):

I've never had to work with a DynamicPropertyInstance in a plugin so I can't speak to its viability for plugins. But, if the Plugin Registration Tool doesn't show it, you may be out of luck.

However, there is a way to still leverage the out-of-box quote line calculation. You could create a separate "# of Users" field. That coupled with the Duration field captures the data you need.

The person creating the quote would populate the "# of Users" and Duration fields. Then your plugin can multiply # of Users * Duration to get the total number of user-months and put that into the out-of-box Quantity field.

The per-item price of $10 is the monthly price per user, so setting the quantity to user-months should do the trick. In your example, Quantity would be 60 (5 users for 12 months).

Comment: I had considered adding a field directly to the quote detail entity as another option, but properties are a much cleaner user experience so I want to explore those first.